# A very strange way of writing arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, initialization, comma-operator

```
template<typename T>
void print(T &t) {
    cout << t << " ";
}

template<typename ...Ts>
void gogo(Ts&& ...agvs) {
    int arr[] = {  (print(agvs),0)... };
    cout << "\n";
    for (auto vi:arr)
        cout << vi << " ";
}

template<typename ...Ts>
void go(Ts&& ...agv) {
    gogo(forward<Ts>(agv)...);
}
```

##### The following are actual calls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVQzJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iro1i.png)

I don't understand this `(print(agvs),0)...`

Why it works this way?

Comment: You should add the code that calls these functions and the output as text to your question.

Comment: note: it should use fold expression if available (c++17) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the comma operator. It evaluates the LHS followed by the RHS, and returns the value of the RHS.

Thus

```
print(agvs),0
```

first evaluates `print(agvs)` and then `0`. The entire expression evaluates to 0.

The `...` is [parameter pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). The compiler will insert `(print(agvs),0)` for each value in `agvs` where `agvs` is substituted with the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

This expression

```
(print(agvs),0)
```

is an expression with the comma operator. Its value is the value of the second operand.

From the C++ 14 Standard (5.19 Comma operator)

> 1 The comma operator groups left-to-right. A pair of expressions
> separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression
> is a discardedvalue expression (Clause 5).87 Every value computation
> and side effect associated with the left expression is sequenced
> before every value computation and side effect associated with the
> right expression. The type and value of the result are the type and
> value of the right operand; the result is of the same value category
> as its right operand, and is a bit-field if its right operand is a
> glvalue and a bit-field. If the value of the right operand is a
> temporary (12.2), the result is that temporary.

So the array is zero-initialized. And the side effect of such an initialization is outputting passed to the function arguments.